# Audio POT with FET and PWM

Tags: transistors, mosfet, audio, pwm, potentiometer

I've been trying to build a simple audio pot to be controlled with PWM with an arduino, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work. I could do it with a LED (not directly which is simple, but with a FET), but audio seems much more complicated.

Here is the schematic so far...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpDuX4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I probably need to connect something to the ground of the Arduino, I tried a few things but it didn't work.

The datasheet for the JFET is here:
http://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Fairchild-Semiconductor/J202/?qs=ljbEvF4DwONNF0IklNND3Q%3d%3d

I just want to be able to control the level like a digital pot.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: **This will not work**, either no sound or unattenuated sound comes through, and you will add a 400 Hz tone to the signal as that is the frequency of the PWM signal from the Arduino. My suggestion: look at similar projects on the internet to see how others do this.

Comment: Hi..I couldn't find other projects of people controlling a potentiometer with PWM. I thought it wouldn't add to the signal like in BJTs..for being a FET I thought the gate would only control the signal level. Actually this was the answer someone gave me here in another question...are you sure there is no way?

Comment: Erm... Jxxx is a JFET, not a MOSFET. Bit of a different beastie there...

Comment: I also thought it was a JFET, but then I read in another website that this one was a MOSFET (http://alltransistors.com/mosfet/transistor.php?transistor=19203)...but that was a mistake! This is indeed a JFET I'm using.. I will change my question to FET in this case.

Comment: *are you sure there is no way* There are ways but not like what you propose, not with a MOSFET, not with unfiltered PWM from an Arduino. A JFET: maybe but you will need some extra circuitry around that. Transistors cannot be used as a potmeter for audio as simple as that. The easiest is to get a dedicated volume control chip. See this: http://embedded-lab.com/blog/lm386-based-stereo-audio-amplifier-with-digital-volume-control/

Comment: I agree with @FakeMoustache - this can never work. Try using a digital potentiometer.

Comment: is it possible to control a volume control chip with PWM?

Comment: Sure, filter the PWM signal resulting in a DC voltage, feed to a DAC, read DAC with an Arduino, Control digital potmeter chip from that Arduino. There it is possible, is it practical ? **NO**

Comment: I see...OK.. I don't want to complicate things...so I lost hope of using a transistor for audio signals. I will change my plans and use a digital pot controlled by serial mode.

Comment: If anyone wants to post an answer explaining why this is not feasible and practical, we can close this thread. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Yes it is possible to use a filtered PWM signal, feed that to a JFET and do some volume control. Will that work ? **yes** Will that work nicely, having a nice controllable volume control ? **No**. That is why almost no-one does it that way.

Comment: I'd go with a class D amp with digital volume control instead of trying to half-analog it.

Comment: Is it possible to find such a thing? A 5v amp with digital volume control?

Comment: A better question is... how do you stop tripping over them? :P

Comment: sorry, I didn't get it..I thought they were small modules..I'm confused now. Do you always trip over your amplifiers? :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PWM to Analog using a DAC chip in order to emulate a Potentiometer for audio](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/241469/convert-pwm-to-analog-using-a-dac-chip-in-order-to-emulate-a-potentiometer-for-a)

Comment: Yes, I asked that question, which is not the same but similar. Before, one of the answers was telling me to use a FET, which I couldn't manage to do it. That's why I created this question.